# convert do cubic-bezier to rtl

Tags: css

I'm a traying convert Css cubic-bezier to RTL

I have this code:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.16, .68, .43, .99);
-moz-transition: -moz-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.16, .68, .43, .99);
-o-transition: -o-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.16, .68, .43, .99);
 transition: transform .2s cubic-bezier(.16, .68, .43, .99);
```

This is my try:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform -.2s cubic-bezier(.16, .68, .43, .99);
-moz-transition: -moz-transform -.2s cubic-bezier(.16, .68, .43, .99);
-o-transition: -o-transform -.2s cubic-bezier(.16, .68, .43, .99);
 transition: transform -.2s cubic-bezier(.16, .68, .43, .99);
```

any help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve with `-.2s`. We could help you if you clarify exactly what is your expected result.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py im trying Mirror moving from left to right TO right to left

Comment: You should post all the relevant code on a Snippet.